# Flattening Nested CSV in Hierarchal order using Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to flatten a nested csv in hierarchal order where 1 is the root node that can be repeatable . Rest of the nodes are children to its corresponding immediate parent and each node is having unique number(Id)
Example two 2s are siblings and 3 is the child of immediate last 2. Similarly node 3(1465) has child 4 (id:2345)  and another 3 (0987) has child 4(3450)

| label | desc | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | jhfdjhfd | 1234 |
| 2 | hdjhfdf | 3456 |
| 2 | mnvmcvn | 8765 |
| 3 | nvbvhv | 1456 |
| 4 | bvnvnv | 2345 |
| 3 | yrtuy | 0987 |
| 4 | uoio | 3450 |

The output should be in following format

| label | desc | id | L0 | L1 | L2 | L3 | L4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | jhfdjhfd | 1234 | null | null | null | null | null |
| 2 | hdjhfdf | 3456 | 1234 | null | null | null | null |
| 2 | mnvmcvn | 8765 | 1234 | null | null | null | null |
| 3 | nvbvhv | 1456 | 1234 | 8765 | null | null | null |
| 4 | bvnvnv | 2345 | 1234 | 8765 | 1456 | null | null |
| 3 | yrtuy | 0987 | 1234 | 8765 | null | null | null |
| 4 | uoio | 3450 | 1234 | 8765 | 0987 | null | null |

Comment: It looks like you've forgotten to include what you've done so far.

Comment: I am not getting any clue unfortunately 